# Settings in pdf::table perl

Tags: perl, pdf

I'm trying to create a table in PDF format using PDF::Table in perl.
However, it seem to not read my header/cols/rows settings.

Here's my code for the table:

```
    use PDF::API2;
    use PDF::Table;

    my $pdftable = new PDF::Table;
    my $pdf  = PDF::API2->new();
    my $page = $pdf->page;
    #data
    my $some_data =[ 
    ["1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],
    ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],
    ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],
    ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],
    ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],# x 100 time to have pages
    ];

    #build the table layout
    $pdftable->table(
     $pdf,
     $page,
     $some_data,
     x => 5,
     w => 600,
     start_y => 750,
     next_y  => 750,
     start_h => 700,
     next_h  => 700,
     # some optional params
     font_size => 8,
     border => 0,
     background_color_odd  => "white",
     background_color_even => "lightblue",
     header_props   => $hdr_props, # see section HEADER ROW PROPERTIES
    );

    $hdr_props = 
        {
            # This param could be a pdf core font or user specified TTF.
            #  See PDF::API2 FONT METHODS for more information
            font       => $pdf->corefont("Times", -encoding => "utf8"),
            font_size  => 10,
            font_color => '#006666',
            bg_color   => 'yellow',
            repeat     => 1,    # 1/0 eq On/Off  if the header row should be repeated to every new page
        };
print "Content-Type: application/pdf;\n\n";
binmode(STDOUT);
print $pdf->stringify;
```

It should make the first row as header by default but the output shows no header properties being set on the first row. And there is no header shown for all pages.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you add `use strict; use warnings;` to the top?

Answer (score 1):

I did not run your code.

You are referencing `$hdr_props` before the variable is filled. Perl does not work that way, you need to order definitions properly.

Add `use strict; use warnings FATAL => 'all';` to the top of your programs and Perl will alert you about mistakes like this.

Answer (score 0):

theres no warnings at all, and i followed daxim to put the $hdr_props to top first but it still would not read in the header settings.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that header_props needs to be a hash reference, so:

```
header_props   => \$hdr_props, # see section HEADER ROW PROPERTIES
```

I ran into a similar problem. However, *daxim* is right, you should also order your code as he suggested.